# Looking for a NoSQL database that store the JSON but does care about the structure to write the document

Tags: nosql

I am trying to write a json/csv file to a database that is coming from a third party site. Occasionally the headers change but the data definition is the same. They might add columns or new fields. I would love to have a database that I could map the changes after so that I could pull the fields together to report. Example if fields were "Daily Sales" for a while and then they changed it to "Sales", I could run report on total sales for the year.